# How to keep an image size intrinsic, before it is loaded, so layout is stable?

Tags: html, css, image, intrinsic-content-size

I had always thought you could specify an `<img/>`'s `width` and `height` attributes so the browser knows its physical dimensions without having to download (at least the header) first. But apparently the attributes are treated as CSS properties - and are thus overridden when you try to do something like `width: 50%; height: auto`. Then, **until the image is downloaded, the computed height remains 0**.
Is there a way to explicitly set the image's physical dimensions (effectively its aspect ratio) via HTML/CSS?

(...and avoid "flashes of unknown aspect ratio" / lots of nervous re-layouting when using Masonry - which you could perhaps work around, but I'm more interested in the basic problem. Even if i'm struggling with asking succinctly about it :)

Comment: `width: 50%;` means 50% of parent's width. The actual size of image doesn't matter. I don't see where you're having an issue

Comment: @warkentien2 well the image's actual size *actually does matter* when its (auto) height is computed - and if you use a percentage, this happens after the image is downloaded, while it could be done earlier if there was a way to hint at its actual size or aspect ratio.

Comment: there must be something with JavaScript. html right: <body onload="checkImageSize()"> then right a checkImageSize() JavaScript function to handle whatever you want it to handle.

Comment: @warkentien2 setting something like `.naturalWidth` has no effect; computing an (absolute) height from a relative width would mess things up sooner or later... plus, waiting for a script to load/download/dom-ready-run would defy the purpose of doing things earlier + it would introduce a sort of race condition between the script and the browser catching up when it has downloaded the image headers. Finally, I had asked for a solution "via HTML/CSS".

Comment: I think what you're asking for here is magic. If I got this straight, you want to know the aspect ratio of an image _before_ getting the image? What you can do is something like `min-height: 50px;` so that it doesn't start out with 0 height, but then again, you said _"computing an (absolute) height from a relative width would mess things up sooner or later"_... I think you've got a fine pickle here

Comment: @MatheusAvellar i don't know if it's _that magic_ - as _I_ do know the aspect ratio of the image and can tell the browser, via `<img width="x" height="y" />` - or so I thought. Essentially, I want the browser to trust me on the image's dimensions and not assume they're 0 or undefined until download...

Comment: @MatheusAvellar but yes, a fine pickle indeed, apparently :)

Comment: Check [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tfggr3fs/) on an idea I had for your issue.. Let me know if it's helpful at all. Basically, I'm setting the proportions of the image (in this case, 4 × 3) with [`vw`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) (decent browser support, but might not be the right thing for your case) when it's still loading (with a `preload` class). I then hooked an `onload` to the `<img>` to remove the `preload` class, which then sets the image to your given `width: 50%; height: auto;`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Updating for 2021, we now have a widely supported standards-compliant way to do this is with the CSS [aspect-ratio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio) property.

You can simply use the height and width like so:

```css
.myimage {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  aspect-ratio: 1280 / 720;
}
```

This will first calculate the width as 50% of the parent element, then, with the height set to auto (it's best to explicitly set it to auto in case something else changes the height for maintainability), it will use the value in aspect-ratio to calculate the height it should reserve.

This *does* affect the image element even after the image has been loaded though. Meaning if the aspect-ratio property doesn't match the image's actual aspect ratio, the image will be stretched to fit. You can prevent this by prepending the "auto" value.

```css
aspect-ratio: auto 1280 / 720;
```

With that, it will use the defined aspect ratio before the image is loaded and the actual aspect ratio is known, then fall back to auto once the browser knows the intrinsic aspect ratio.

This is not supported by non-standard browsers like Internet Explorer and Safari, so if you want to make this work in those purely with CSS, you'll need to continue using the first workaround in [kubi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55867053/9992172) (as a side note, the 4th option is not and has never been on track to become part of the standard).

*However*, this question would likely not even get asked if it were today (at least not by the same person) because there is now an HTML solution which is the old, pre-responsive web design HTML solution. Most modern browsers now use the image element's height and width attributes to calculate the aspect ratio, while CSS height and width override those values unless they are set to auto.

Therefore...

```html
<img src='myimage.jpg' class='myimage' width='1280' height='720' />
```

```css
.myimage {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
}
```

This will now reserve the correct amount of vertical height, even in Safari. As of right now, there are still some [browser-specific implementation notes](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_img_aspect_ratio_computed_from_attributes) to consider.

In Chromium and Firefox, it is currently implemented using the CSS aspect-ratio property with "auto" prepending the calculated aspect ratio.

```css
aspect-ratio: auto attr(width) / attr(height);
```

Since Safari doesn't support the aspect-ratio property yet as of my writing this, its implementation has a bit more nuance. As a result, it will not reserve space if there is not a valid image value in the src attribute, meaning if you are using old-fashioned JavaScript-based image lazy loading, you will need to include a fallback image.

In any case, you should include height and width attributes on your image tags as much as possible. They actually do something now.

Comment: excellent answer, i don't know why i get around to it only now. definitely the way to go in 2021+. and it explains why i have been noticing a decrease in "nervous re-layouting" over the past years. interesting case of web things getting quietly better without breaking *anything*, to my knowledge!

Answer (score 9):

So, as soon as we set `height: auto` by CSS, the browser ignores the intrinsic size set by `width` and `height` HTML attributes.

Possible workarounds and a possible solution for the future:

1. Use the Intrinsic Ratio Box hack

   ```html
   <div style="height: 0; padding-bottom: 42.857%; position: relative">
     <img style="position: absolute; left: 0; height: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%" … />
   </div>
   ```
2. Using data URIs and JavaScript pre-load a placeholder with the same aspect ratio (beware of rounding errors!)

   ```
   <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQIAJQAlAAD/2wBDAFA3PEY8MlBGQUZaVVBfeMiCeG5uePWvuZHI////////////////////////////////////////////////////wAALCAAPACMBAREA/8QAFgABAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEE/8QAFBABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/aAAgBAQAAPwDQgoICv//Z"
     onload="this.src='https://via.placeholder.com/3500x1500.jpg'"/>
   ```

   If we are using the "blurry placeholder" technique, the framework might already be there.
3. Same as two, but use an SVG - easier to create on the fly, but no blurry placeholder "for free", obviously

   ```
   <img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
     width='350px' height='150px'%3E%3C/svg%3E"
     onload="this.src='https://via.placeholder.com/3500x1500.jpg'"/>
   ```
4. If & once `intrinsicsize` lands ([WICG](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/intrinsic-size/), [github/Chrome](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/intrinsic-size/)) and gets adopted, there will be a Proper Way to do this:

   ```html
   <img intrinsicsize="350x150" width="…
   ```

All of these have downsides, of course.
You can try 2 & 3 in [this Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPYLOJ) - it would need more work & testing, I'll probably wait for 4, which I consider a fix for something that shouldn't need fixing. Stupid browsers :)

Comment: Your third solution is what I was looking for the whole damn day

Comment: Solution nr. 3 is very nice, thanks! One error here though is that you want to also remove the onload handler, like this: onload="this.onload=null; this.src='...". Otherwise you go into an infinite loop, using crazy amounts of CPU. At least in firefox 82.

Comment: here we are in 2022 and `intrinsicsize` did not make it. if you need legacy solutions use 1 thru 3, otherwise see @XerBlade's answer