# Image intrisic size is different from its given size CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to insert the Facebook logo on a custom registration button I created. I set the size of the image to 50x50 according to the code below

```
img{
    /*here*/
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    color:blue;
  }
```

And it effectively sets the size of the image to 50x50 on the button, but the intrinsic size of the image is 1x1 (i.e width:1px; height:1px) and I don't understand why it does that. see below

[image]
[image]

please I need help

Comment: Are you sure that the image is loaded correctly?

Comment: What is the actual size of the image you are linking to?

Comment: the size of the image is 72x72

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55867053/13536893)

Answer (score 0):

not 100% sure but try to add this to your `img` element.

```
<img intrinsicsize="50 x 50">
```

also, read [this](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/intrinsic-size/) article

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that the problem was the path to the images thanks for your help

Comment: Mark your question as solved by this answer, please.